How to separate dynaconf settings for each environment in it's own file?
Im using dynaconf 3.2.4 to load my config files. I want have seperate files for each environment: config.dev.yaml, config.test.yaml, config.prod.yaml, etc.
I want to keep my files simple and do without the unnecessary indentation.
For config.dev.yaml instead of
dev:
  version: 1
  name: 'dev settings'

I want
version: 1
name: 'dev settings'

My current settings:
settings = Dynaconf(
    envvar_prefix="MYPREFIX",
    settings_files=["config/config.dev.yaml", "config/config.test.yaml", "config/config.prod.yaml"],
    environments=True,
    env="dev",
)

How do i need to configure dyaconf to load each environment correctly?
Running with the above settings i get
settings.current_env # 'DEVELOPMENT'
settings.name # 'Settings' object has no attribute 'NAME'

Setting environments=False results in
settings.current_env # 'main'
settings.name # 'prod settings'

It seems to load only the last specified yaml file.
Same problem (without solution) found here: https://github.com/dynaconf/dynaconf/discussions/956
